# Can use `animate` with `onslide` in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animate

I saw one example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate,tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
\begin{center}
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{1}
      \multiframe{15}{i=0+1}{%
        \tikz{\path node {\Huge\bf \i};}
      }%
    \end{animateinline}
\end{center}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to use this variable to `\onslide<\i->{...}` or not. What easy way to use `animate` with `onslide` or `only` in beamer and tikz.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the effect you want to achieve by using the counter `\i`? Surely you can use the `\i` counter *inside* the `\multiframe` group. But the output would be quite odd, wouldn't it: You're going to have 14 pages, each page contains an animation, and the `\i`th frame of the animation on the `\i`th page will potentially be different...

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach to what you seek by using beamer.  The number will be shown on each slide starting from 0 to 15.  The approach does not need animate package but OP's constraint is met. It has exactly the same output as the animate would have done.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate,tikz,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\foreach \i  in {0,1,...,15}{
\only<\numexpr{\i+1}>{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\node at (current page.center) {\Huge\bf \i};}}
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** Commented by Kevin C, this attemp re-exams the previous solution and the question again. This new solution uses `animate` package and `oneside`.

For slide one: it will count from 0 to 1 automatically.

For the third slide: it will count from 0 to 3 automatically.

For the 14th slide: it will count from 0 to 14 automatically.

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{1}
      \multiframe{15}{i=0+1}{
      \onslide<\i->{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node at (current page.center) {\Huge\bf \i};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      }}
    \end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `\foreach \i in {1,...,15} \only<\i>{...}`, and hence no need to load `calc` package? Also, the output isn't quite "exactly" the same: with `animate`, the animation is automatic, while with Beamer overlay, the "animation" is manual - one has to click some buttons for the "animated" effects to be shown. `:)`

Comment: @KevinC -- If my memory serves me well, I was thinking the OP wanted to start countering from 0 to 15. Yes, you are right. I presented an alternative.